# Setting MediaStreamProperties on HoloLens does not work

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

I am working on an UWP app for the HoloLens to read single frames from the devices camera. I want to use the camera mode with the lowest resolution available.

I took a look at the following links and examples and tried to create a minimal working app:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/set-media-encoding-properties
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/use-opencv-with-mediaframereader
- https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution
- https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraOpenCV

This is the code snippet from MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
  public async Task<int> Start()
        {
            // Find the sources 
            var allGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();
            var sourceGroups = allGroups.Select(g => new
            {
                Group = g,
                SourceInfo = g.SourceInfos.FirstOrDefault(i => i.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color)
            }).Where(g => g.SourceInfo != null).ToList();

            if (sourceGroups.Count == 0)
            {
                // No camera sources found
                return 0;
            }
            var selectedSource = sourceGroups.FirstOrDefault();

            // Initialize MediaCapture
            _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
            {
                SourceGroup = selectedSource.Group,
                SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl,
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu
            };
            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);


            // Query all properties of the device 
            IEnumerable<StreamResolution> allVideoProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoRecord).Select(x => new StreamResolution(x));

            // Order them by resolution then frame rate
            allVideoProperties = allVideoProperties.OrderBy(x => x.Height * x.Width).ThenBy(x => x.FrameRate);

            await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoRecord, allVideoProperties.ElementAt(0).EncodingProperties);

            // Create the frame reader
            MediaFrameSource frameSource = _mediaCapture.FrameSources[selectedSource.SourceInfo.Id];

            _reader = await _mediaCapture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(frameSource, MediaEncodingSubtypes.Bgra8);
            _reader.FrameArrived += ColorFrameReader_FrameArrivedAsync;
            await _reader.StartAsync();

            return 1;
        }


 private async void ColorFrameReader_FrameArrivedAsync(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
        {

            var frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
            if (frame != null)
            {
                var inputBitmap = frame.VideoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;         
            }
        }
```

On my local machine (MacBookPro with Bootcamp partition) this code works using the webcam. It detects three supported video modes. I can change the resolution of the bitmap image in `FrameArrivedAsync`  by changing the index from 0 to 1 or 2 at:

`_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoRecord, allVideoProperties.ElementAt(0).EncodingProperties);`

On HoloLens this code does not work. It detects the different modes like explained here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable-camera). But setting the MediaStreamProperties does not change anything regarding the received bitmap image. The bitmap is always 1280x720.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, we want to share how we setup the capture profile, you can refer to the following code with annotate to modify your project for testing. If in doubt, please feel free to add comments.

```cs
        private async void SetupAndStartMediaCapture()
        {
            string deviceId = string.Empty;
            _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

            DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                if(MediaCapture.IsVideoProfileSupported(device.Id))
                {
                    deviceId = device.Id; 
                    break; // The video device for which supported video profile support is queried.
                }
            }

            MediaCaptureInitializationSettings mediaCapSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                VideoDeviceId = deviceId
            };

            IReadOnlyList<MediaCaptureVideoProfile> profiles = MediaCapture.FindAllVideoProfiles(deviceId); 

            var profileMatch = (
                from profile in profiles
                from desc in profile.SupportedRecordMediaDescription
                where desc.Width == 896 && desc.Height == 504 && desc.FrameRate == 24     // HL1
                select new { profile, desc }
).FirstOrDefault();// Select the Profile with the required resolution from all available profiles.

            if (profileMatch != null)
            {
                mediaCapSettings.VideoProfile = profileMatch.profile;
                mediaCapSettings.RecordMediaDescription = profileMatch.desc;
            }

            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaCapSettings); //Initializes the MediaCapture object.
        }
```